# Broadcasting message and message handler function to windows attached to process

Tags: visual-c++, wtl

Is there a way to have a single message handler function that will be called for WM_SETCURSOR for all the windows attached to the process, instead of writing the same code for all types of windows in the application?

Comment: So basically you have a bunch of windows in your application. Most but not all are derived from cwindow, and for every window you have a message dispatcher but you want a handler to handle all the cursor updates from all the windows in your application, even if they are not derived from the same class.  



Probably you have sibling / child windows witch don't handle the parent's, let's say "busy" icon, properly, is this your case ?

Comment: They're all a `CWnd` at the core (customs derived from Windows Template Library), dialogs, buttons, listboxes. I've set the a handler for `WM_SETCURSOR` in the main dialog to `IDC_WAIT`, but when moving the cursor on another sibling window, the cursor changes to normal. So it only works for the part of the window which doesn't have any other window component on top.

Comment: In WTL, see `CMessageLoop::AddMessageFilter`. You can intercept and pre-process messages right after they are retrieved from the message queue, and before they are dispatched to the destination window.